# Jsoup.parse returning invalid HTML

Tags: html, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup to parse arbitrary HTML and it's been working well so far, but I've run into a problem. When given the following HTML, Jsoup returns invalid HTML (extraneous bits removed):

```
<div>
  <a href=''>
    <img src='' alt='The problem is here "I'm not sure what to do"'>
  </a>
</div>
```

I've got an `alt` tag enclosed with single quotes that contains unescaped single quotes and double quotes and I don't have any control over the input unfortunately. When I run this through `Jsoup.parse`, I get this:

```
<div>
  <a href="">
    <img src="" alt="The problem is here &quot;I" m not sure what to do"'>
  </a>
</div>
```

Those two unclosed quotations at the end of the `img` tag are screwing me up. I was hoping Jsoup would give me something along the lines of:

```
<div>
  <a href="">
    <img src="" alt="The problem is here &quot;I'm not sure what to do&quot;">
  </a>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

jsoup's homepage advertises:

> jsoup implements the WHATWG HTML5 specification, and parses HTML to the same DOM as modern browsers do.

… which is what it is doing.

So, no, you can't make it parse the code the way you want.

You'll need to fix your errors before passing the content to jsoup.

Comment: Any suggestions for how to fix the content before passing it to Jsoup?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
<div>
  <a href="">
    <img src="" alt="The problem is here &#34;I&#39;m not sure what to do&#34;">
  </a>
</div>
```